# Validation not strictly required for Event Grid subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication) for Azure Event Grid says

> Your app needs to respond by echoing back the validation code. Event Grid does not deliver events to WebHook endpoints that have not passed the validation.

I created my WebHook Azure Function, which just OK's any POST request, without validation code. Nonetheless, I still see the custom events that I send coming to this endpoint.

Why isn't validation strictly required in this case?

Comment: Are you testing this with requestb.in? Or is it a custom endpoint?

Comment: @PacodelaCruz It's a custom endpoint. I don't need requestb.in to test. Just create an azure function, add it as subscription endpoint and log all incoming requests.

Comment: I was told by the product team that I should only expect that behaviour on requestb.in as is whitelisted. This can be because it's preview. They know the current approach is cumbersome and are working on improving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token exchange happens behind the scenes for Azure Functions, so you don't need to echo back the validation code. The same applies to Logic Apps.

Comment: Any docs about how that works? What if I point Event Grid to a Function from another subscription?

Comment: It works with a function from another subscription (just tested). There isn't any documentation on this at the moment.

Comment: Do I can DDoS any function on Earth?

Comment: No, because there are throttling and retry mechanisms in place to avoid that. The subscriber (function) will still need to ack the request from grid as well. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an "Event Grid Trigger" based Azure Function as your event subscription destination, the subscription validation is handled automatically. Starting 2018-01-01 API version, if you are using a "HTTP trigger" based function (as your destination endpoint during event subscription creation), you will need to handle this validation in your code. This is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview.

Here is some **sample** code in C#:

Step 1: Add a dependency to Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid:
To do this, click on the "View Files" link in your Azure Function (right most pane in the Azure functions portal), and create a file called project.json. Add the following contents to the project.json file and save it:

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "net46": {
            "dependencies": {
               "Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid": "1.1.0-preview"
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Step 2: Handling the Subscription Validation Event:

```
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid.Models;

class SubscriptionValidationEventData
{
    public string ValidationCode { get; set; }
}

class SubscriptionValidationResponseData
{
    public string ValidationResponse { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req,  TraceWriter log)
{
    string response = string.Empty;
    const string SubscriptionValidationEvent  = "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent";

    string requestContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    EventGridEvent[] eventGridEvents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventGridEvent[]>(requestContent);

    foreach (EventGridEvent eventGridEvent in eventGridEvents)
    {
        JObject dataObject = eventGridEvent.Data as JObject;

        // Deserialize the event data into the appropriate type based on event type
        if (string.Equals(eventGridEvent.EventType, SubscriptionValidationEvent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var eventData = dataObject.ToObject<SubscriptionValidationEventData>();
            log.Info($"Got SubscriptionValidation event data, validation code {eventData.ValidationCode}, topic={eventGridEvent.Topic}");
            // Do any additional validation (as required) and then return back the below response
            var responseData = new SubscriptionValidationResponseData();
            responseData.ValidationResponse = eventData.ValidationCode;
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseData);   
        }            
    }

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);    
}
```